# ERC20 Token transfer with Web3JS on Infura Ropsten Testnet - Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: node.js, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, erc20

So, after one day of searching and many purple links I cannot do anything else but to ask a question about the topic asked a dozen times, yet somehow each issue is unique to its own.

**Info**:

- Node v12.16.1
- Ropsten Testnet via Infura API
- "web3": "1.2.6"
- "ethereumjs-tx": "2.1.2"
- [ERC20 token example](https://github.com/bitfwdcommunity/Issue-your-own-ERC20-token/blob/master/contracts/erc20_tutorial.sol) , changed Token name and decimals to 8 and `pragma solidity ^0.5.2;`

**Important note:** Smart contract is compiled and deployed via Remix (using 0.5.3 compiler), `transfer()` method tested successfully via Metamask.

**This code produces this bug:** - Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const compiled = require("./compile");
const Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction;

const contractAddress = "0x27...";

const address = "0x02...";
const privateKey = "A475...";

const bufferedPrivKey = Buffer.from(privateKey, "hex");

const rpcUrl = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/{INFURA_API_KEY}";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcUrl));

const call = async () => {
try {
    const abi = compiled.abi; //copied from remix

    const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
    from: address
    });

    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address);

    const data = await contract.methods.transfer("0x2B0...", 1000).encodeABI();

    const rawTx = {
    from: address,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
    gas: web3.utils.toHex(100000),
    data: data,
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
    value: 0x00,
    chainId: 0x03 //ropsten i guess?
    };

    const tx = new Tx(rawTx, { chain: "ropsten" });
    tx.sign(bufferedPrivKey);

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"));
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.stack);
}
};

call();
```

**Fun facts:**

- I was having the same issue when i tried to deploy smart contract via `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction()`
- Following the rabbit hole I've found potential [solution](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2518#issuecomment-476088154) to lower web3 version to **1.0.0-beta.34** and when I did, I had gas issues - transfer transaction took ages and eventually I ran out of gas. Most of the issues were:

> intrinsic gas too low

or

> Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas